# Obtener solo el valor más alto de un objeto en json

Tags: php, json, array

Tengo una gran lista de información, pero quiero solamente ver el numero más alto:

```
{
1900: 104,
1901: 103,
1902: 84,
1903: 93,
1904: 103,
1905: 97,
1906: 116,
}
```

codigo para obtener esa información:

```
$values = $this->getService(); //return decode json
$total = array();
        foreach ($values as $code) {
            $sku = $code['birthYear'];
            if (!isset($totals[$sku])) {
               $totals[$sku] = 0;
            }
            $totals[$sku] ++;
         }    
         echo json_encode($totals);
```

> Como puedo solo mostrar el numero mas elevado dependiente del año es decir que solo muestre: `1906: 116`

Utilizando max, logre traer el valor pero no el año:
`echo max($totals);`

```
output : 116
```

Comment: Hola, como seria esa relacion no entendi eso, el numero mas alto es 116 ahi me perdi

Comment: cierto cierto! es 116, sorry!

Comment: Y porque tendría q mostrar el año 1900?

Comment: Listo @ManucoBianco es 1906

Comment: Chequea [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6676851/7291849) que puede q te ayude. Usa el arreglo `$totals`

Answer (score 0):

EL maximo valor de un array lo puedes obtener con la funcion `max()` para obtner su llave se me ocurre que puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$max = max($values);
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    if ($max==$value) {
        $anio  = $key;
    }
}
echo "max= ".$max." año=".$anio;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

Obtienes el valor mas alto del arreglo:

```
$value = max($array);
```

Y luego obtienes el key de ese valor. Recuerda que si tienes varios indices con el mismo valor `array_search` te devolverá la primer coincidencia.:

```
$key = array_search($value, $array);
```

Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Con este codigo puedes obtener ambas:

```php
$arr = array( 1 => "A", 10 => "B", 5 => "C" );

//obtienes la llave 
$key = max(array_keys($arr));
var_dump($key);


//obtienes el valor
var_dump($arr[$key]);
```